# Error amplifier in PWM controller

Tags: operational-amplifier, dc-dc-converter, pspice, bode-plot, error-amplifier

Using the datasheet [UC3842 PWM Controller](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uc3842.pdf) I have modelled error amplifier in it.

- AC analysis of error amplifier matches with the datasheet plot(Figure 3) 
  [image: Schematic]

[image]
 - Since I need to clamp the output voltages(transient) of the error amplifier (COMP) I had placed higher and lower clamps but unfortunately my Aol and behavior of gain and phase change.
 - Clamps are needed during transient behavior
[image: Schematic with clamp] 
 - Is there any better way to model the error amplifier which I can match both bode plot Aol and transient behavior of the amplifier in PSpice.

Comment: Why not use TI's SPICE model that's available on their product page for the part?

Comment: Since its has been modeled using transistors it takes simulation time and I want to get same behavior by duplicating the same behavior in spice modelling.